# Render text with BitmapFont in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to a "life count" to Bob with a `BitmapFont` in the **libgdx demo Super Jumper**. I added:

```
Assets.font.draw(batch, "20", world.bob.position.x, world.bob.position.y);
```

in the `renderBob()` method of `WorldRenderer` class.

But the text is rendered in a huge size and barely can be seen at the bottom of the screen:

[image: Super Jumper Bob jumps over a giant "2"]

What should I do to make the life count text render correctly on top of Bob's head?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WorldRenderer-class you have a different camera/resolution setting, there is only a resolution of:

`static final float FRUSTUM_WIDTH = 10;
static final float FRUSTUM_HEIGHT = 15;`

So what you have to do is:
Draw your String inside `GameScreen.presentRunning`, but you have to recalculate the Position of Bob to your GameScreen-Camera.

I think this should work inside presentRunning (can't test right now):

`Assets.font.draw(batcher, "20", world.bob.position.x / 10 * 320, world.bob.position.y / 15 * 480);`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your method, it is working for first few step but the text is moving upwards faster than bob and eventually went off from top of the screen.


I think this is because the guiCam is not moving but our text is following `world.bob.position.y`. 

What do you think?

Comment: This should work: :) `float maxY = world.bob.position.y;
  if(maxY > 15/2)
   maxY = 15/2;
  
  Assets.font.draw(batcher, "20", world.bob.position.x / 10 * 320, maxY / 15 * 480);`